# Factorization of the semi-palprime $N = pq$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, decimal-expansion

I define `semi-palprime` be a prime number that remains the prime when its digits are reversed, like $p = 13$, and its mate is $q = 31$. I know that number $N$,

$ N = \\40276504015957241212219140055284581853797537049211403507316894593383\\
47457987912639871372112187693426311212748251225732519905589136273168\\
20318858996928988487350273731350467362899934942766591227002091985684\\
14312802147969417515545625068960627407674722275954470998513985249290\\
2998963539890226770447590949818014983$

is the product of one semi-palprime number $p$ and its mate $q$, how I can factorize $N$?

Comment: Does this have any cryptographic applications?

Comment: @outs I don't know, but you can suppose that some app generate RSA keys with this feature, $p$ and $q$ such that $p$ is semi-palprime number and $q$ is its mate. Now you want to break that RSA key, and I have asked how.

Comment: @outs You are right, but I think that finding that prime is an algorithmic way and I need an optimized algorithm to find $p$ and $q$, coz the digits of $p$ are reversed in $q$ and we know the product of them, $N$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about recreational mathematics, and not crypto at all (not all factoring questions are cryptographically interesting)

Comment: This could be cryptographically interesting if 1) the "semi-palprime" pair was easy to find and 2) if it wasn't significantly easier to factor. Unfortunately that doesn't seem the case, but I guess it can be called crypto (as in: analyzing a new generation system for RSA key pairs). We've seen worse ideas here :)

Comment: I think this question is ok if it is reformulated as _"What are some algorithms to factorize a number, given that it is a semi-palprime?"_

Comment: Call me picky, but _semi-palprime_ is used in the title in a way that's incompatible with the definition given in the body.

Answer (score 6):

You work at both ends towards the middle; if you know the lower $n$ digits of $p$, you can immediately deduce the lower $n$ digits of $q$, as $q \equiv N p^{-1} \pmod{10^n}$

Similarly, if you know the upper $n$ digits of $p$, you have a bound on the upper $n$ digits of $q$, as if you know that $p$ is in the range $(p_0, p_1)$, then $q$ must be in the range $(N/p_1, N/p_0)$

So, look through the possible values of the lower two digits of $p$, deduce the corresponding lower two digits of $q$.  Now, because the primes are mirror images of each other, this implies the upper two digits; check to see if the corresponding upper digits are compatible.  Some will be, most won't be; reject the possibilities that aren't.

For the possibilities that are, then go through the possibilities for the third digit; repeat the execise until you meet in the middle.